# How to retrieve values from jQuery/Ajax POST method in Django

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, django-views

While posting an Address Form from client to server using Ajax/jQuery, I receive a string response on the backend. Can someone please advise, How I could process the string and obtain the values it contains.

Below is the Ajax/ jQuery script

```
<script> // Submitting address form via Ajax
    function addressform() {
        var data = $('#addressform').serialize();
        $.post('/suggestions', data);
    }
</script>
```

Below is the string response received on the backend (Django), how can I process it to obtain form fields and its values (e.g. DoorNo = 423, BuildingName = Newstead)

```
"GET /addressform/?DoorNo=423&BuildingName=Newstead&Locality=Hatfield&Area=Herefordshire&City=&Pincode=AL10+9DQ HTTP/1.1" 200 4818
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using 'serialize', you could use [serializeArray()](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/). I find working with JSON is easier.

```
<script> // Submitting address form via Ajax
    function addressform() {
        var data = $('#addressform').serializeArray();
        $.post( '/suggestions', $.toJSON(data) );
    }
</script>
```

And then, in the Django view

```
import json
def receiveSuggestions(request):
    data = json.loads(request.body)
    #
    # Add to database and other stuff
    #
    return HttpResponse( json.dumps({"status" : 1}) )
```

Basically, request.body in the view will give you access to whatever has been sent in the post request. Earlier it was raw_post_data. Maybe this will help? [Where's my JSON data in my incoming Django request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208067/wheres-my-json-data-in-my-incoming-django-request)

Answer (score 1):

Based on your question, it sounds like you are looking to process the data passed by your ajax request from django.

You can look into the `request.POST` for post requests or `request.GET` for get requests to get a dictionary of the key-values you passed.  See the documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.POST).

To provide an example, I'll  you have a view handler for `/addressform/`, let's call it `address_form`

```
def address_form(request):
   if request.method == 'POST':
       # process the post and return appropriate response
       params = request.POST
       door_no = params['DoorNo']
       #etc for each key value
       ...
   else:
       # get on the url, handle return the appropriate response
```