# Django json post request parse

Tags: django, post, web, request

My client is passing this json as a post to django server:

```
data={  'supplier': supplier_name,
        'date': date,
        'payment':payment,
        'materials':[{"name":name,"qtd":qtd,"price":price},
                    {"name":name,"qtd":qtd,"price":price},
                    {"name":name,"qtd":qtd,"price":price}]
}
```

I'm using push to put materials:

```
data['materials'].push({"name":name,"qtd":qtd,"price":price});
```

My django view handles data like this:

```
supplier=request.POST.get('supplier')
date=request.POST.get('date')
```

When I try to do this, the materials content is "none":

```
materials=request.POST.get('materials')
```

How can get a list use in further code?

Ajax is being sent like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"{% url 'validate_purchase' %}",
    data: data,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
    }
});
```

Comment: duplicates https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208067/wheres-my-json-data-in-my-incoming-django-request?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa
see https://stackoverflow.com/a/3244765/6627564 this answer

Comment: is this exact what your client is passing to django app - `{"name":name,"qtd":qtd,"price":price}
                    {"name":name,"qtd":qtd,"price":price}`? Looks like this is not a valid JSON, you missed `,` between `} {` in your `materials` array.

Comment: @Chiefir I missed "," because this was just to exemplify, I am using data['materials'].push({"name":name,"qtd":qtd,"price":price}) to put data

Comment: You should show the part of your JS which actually sends the data. Are you sending it as a form-encoded POST with the JSON in the `data` field, or are you sending it as a JSON POST directly?

Comment: edited, with ajax in jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data to be sent as json must be "stringified", so you need to do "JSON.stringify(data)"

```
$.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"{% url 'validate_purchase' %}",
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        dataType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
        success: function(data){
        }
    });
```

Comment: You can also pass key value pairs as data, e.g. data: `{"key": "value"}`

Answer (score 2):

If you are passing data using `Content-Type: application/json`, You can access `json` from `request.body`

Example:

```
(myblog)  ✘ ✝ ~/projects/myblog/base  up-sell±  curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
--request POST \
--data '{"supplier": "x", "date": "x", "materials": [{"price": "x", "qtd": "x", "name": "x"}, {"price": "x", "qtd": "x", "name": "x"}, {"price": "x", "qtd": "x", "name": "x"}], "payment": "x"}' \
http://localhost:8000/motor/upsell/set-upsell/ \
> -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

views.py:

```
ipdb> import json
ipdb> json.loads(request.body)
{u'supplier': u'x', u'date': u'x', u'materials': [{u'price': u'x', u'qtd': u'x', u'name': u'x'}, {u'price': u'x', u'qtd': u'x', u'name': u'x'}, {u'price': u'x', u'qtd': u'x', u'name': u'x'}], u'payment': u'x'}
```

**Update**:

*Example by ajax call*

Here is ajax function,

```
data = {"supplier": "x", "date": "x", "materials": [{"price": "x", "qtd": "x", "name": "x"}, {"price": "x", "qtd": "x", "name": "x"}, {"price": "x", "qtd": "x", "name": "x"}], "payment": "x"}

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost:8000/motor/upsell/set-upsell/',
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'json'
});
```

Python code,

```
ipdb> import json
ipdb> request.body
'{"supplier":"x","date":"x","materials":[{"price":"x","qtd":"x","name":"x"},{"price":"x","qtd":"x","name":"x"},{"price":"x","qtd":"x","name":"x"}],"payment":"x"}'
ipdb> json.loads(request.body)
{u'supplier': u'x', u'date': u'x', u'materials': [{u'price': u'x', u'qtd': u'x', u'name': u'x'}, {u'price': u'x', u'qtd': u'x', u'name': u'x'}, {u'price': u'x', u'qtd': u'x', u'name': u'x'}], u'payment': u'x'}
ipdb>
```

Comment: Is giving me this error(raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0))